# Why my following ajax is not working in Asynchronous mode

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, asynchronous

below is my code that I call on page load.
it works when I use

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "../handlers/fetchshift.ashx?id=" + divs[i].id, false);
```

but if I use

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "../handlers/fetchshift.ashx?id=" + divs[i].id, true);
```

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange is called for only last div. Why it is happening? I need it in Asynchronous mode.

```
function myfunction() {
     try {

         if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
             xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

         }
         else {// code for IE6, IE5
             xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }

         var table = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>');
         if (table == null) return;
         var divs = table.getElementsByTagName('div');
         for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {

             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                 if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                     var msg = xmlhttp.responseText.split("|");
                     var table = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>');
                     var divs = table.getElementsByTagName('div');
                     for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                         if (divs[i].id == msg[0]) {
                             divs[i].innerHTML = msg[1];
                             divs[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = msg[2];
                         }

                     }
                 }
             }



             xmlhttp.open("GET", "../handlers/fetchshift.ashx?id=" + divs[i].id, false);

             xmlhttp.send();
         }


     } catch (e) {
         alert(e);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `xmlhttp` object inside your `for` cycle. Currently you are overwriting everything each time so only the last request actually goes through.

It works in synchronous mode because `xmlhttp.open()` will block until everything is finished so in the next iteration everything is overwritten but that does not matter anymore.

```
function myfunction() {
     try {
         var table = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>');
         if (table == null) return;
         var divs = table.getElementsByTagName('div');
         for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {

         if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                 xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             }
             else {// code for IE6, IE5
                 xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }

             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                 if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                     var msg = xmlhttp.responseText.split("|");
                     var table = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>');
                     var divs = table.getElementsByTagName('div');
                     for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                         if (divs[i].id == msg[0]) {
                             divs[i].innerHTML = msg[1];
                             divs[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = msg[2];
                         }

                     }
                 }
             }

             xmlhttp.open("GET", "../handlers/fetchshift.ashx?id=" + divs[i].id, false);
             xmlhttp.send();
         }
     } catch (e) {
         alert(e);
     }
}
```